# How to get list of generated terms in a fuzzy query elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest, fuzzy-search

I am trying to implement `"did you mean xxxxx"` functionality using elasticsearch. So, when I dont get any results for a query, I thought of using fuzzy query to get related terms with results and show them to the users: `"did you mean xxx, yyy, zzz"?

`For example if one searches for:`stackooverflow,`I want to return a meesage:`"did you mean: stackoverflow"`?

I played around with `fuzzy query` and it actually works. However, it directly returns the results of the query. Is there a way to return the generated matching terms instead?

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy search is not a tool to be used for did you mean feature.
You can implement it using `suggest` query.
Here is a great link about implementing `did you mean` and `autocomplete` feature using elasticsearch.
[Search like a Google with Elasticsearch. Autocomplete, Did you mean and search for items](http://www.bilyachat.com/2015/07/search-like-google-with-elasticsearch.html)

Comment: thnx mohammad , I ll have a look